# Make knockd listen to a specific IP address

Tags: networking

In Knockd how do I listen to a specific IP address from an interface that has multiple IP addresses?

Knockd only has the option to listen by interface but not an IP address.

For example interface `eth0` has 3 IPs

- `123.123.123.123`
- `124.124.124.124`
- `125.125.125.125`

My target listen IP is `124.124.124.124` but if I start knockd with eth0 interface it will listen to the first ip `123.123.123.123`.

Comment: My guess would be that because knockd doesn't create listeners for itself  but rather listens at the link-layer level you can't bind it to a specific IP-address. But that should make it respond to all IP's bound to an interface.

Comment: as a workaround only allow the IP the knockd service should listen to via firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knockd` works on the interface level, so there's no need or way to bind it to a specific IP address.

> It listens to all traffic on an ethernet (or PPP) interface, looking
> for special "knock" sequences of port-hits.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/knockd

If you need to make a difference in addresses you require multiple interfaces (possibly VLAN subinterfaces) or you need another daemon.

Comment: Meaning I would need to create new interfaces like a bridge or alias type with those adresses and run mutiple knockd daemon for each interfaces?

Comment: A bridge or an alias is no separate interface. If required, you need to use a dedicated physical or logical (sub)interface. Usually, the knocking sequence is the point and not the actual destination address, so I don't really see a scenario where you must make that distinction.

Comment: My scenario is a dedicated server with multiple IPs that are attached to a single interface as alias IPs, I have no control over the attached as it's done by the hosting company. I need the knockd to run for 2 of those IPs individually on different ports using the same sequences.

Comment: I found out the issue was that knockd that comes in ubuntu 20.04 is version 7.0 which only binds to the first IP of the interface and not all of it, the latest version 8.0 binds to all of the interface which solves my issue.